# Core-Bluetooth bi-directional communication

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Reading the docs, i have built 2 apps that connects 2 iDevices using BLE.
One device is Central, and the other is Peripheral.
The Central is looking for the Peripheral , and when find it, explore its services and characteristics, than connect to the relevant characteristic.

When an update is come from that characteristic i want to respond with data from the central to the peripheral .

Question is , do i have to switch from central to peripheral at one side and vise versa at the other side , in order to respond ? means, if i wants to make a simple chat, they always have to switch?
if yes- that makes it a problem to chat because there is a possibility that both devices went to peripheral and are trying to send messages at the same time.

So, if there is a way to make a bi-directional communication, how would one perform that, and any links with tutorials about that would be great . thanx.

Answer (score 5):

The BLE communication is bi-directional already.

**Central -> Peripheral**: write a characteristic.

1. Peripheral has to have a writable characteristic.
2. The Central can write that characteristic this way sending the data.

**Central <- Peripheral**: update the value of the characteristic that the central has subscribed to.

1. Peripheral has to have a dynamic characteristic that it updates the value of.
2. The Central subscribes for notifications/indications on that characteristic.
3. The Peripheral updates the value of the characteristic which in turn sends a notification with the updated value to the Central.

To see how it works, check out the [BTLE Transfer demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html). You should spend some time studying the way it operates. The [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html) also has great examples to get a deeper understanding.

Comment: Have I answered your question? If I have, please mark it as the answer. If not, then please let me know what else would you like to know.

Comment: Is it possible for the peripheral to send a different value for the same characteristic depending on the central?

Comment: @elslooo The [updateValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager/1393281-updatevalue) API has the `onSubscribedCentrals` parameter that you can use to send the update to specific centrals.